# Cant Post directly to sub-resouce in spring boot data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have a basic spring boot data rest api with posts that can have many comments. My problem is that I cant seem to find a way to post my comment directly to the sub resource uri such as http://localhost:8090/posts/1/comments.

The only way I've been able to do it was to to create the comment resource first at http://localhost:8090/comments and then post the uri of comment into http://localhost:8090/posts/1/comments.

It seems like a really bad idea as comments should never be able to exist on their own and only ever linked to a post.

Does anybody know how I can do this as one action, otherwise I'll have to manually deal with potential orphaned comments where the comment gets posted but never gets posted into http://localhost:8090/posts/1/comments for whatever reason.

My code is below.
Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
@Entity
public class Comment extends ResourceSupport {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

private String comment;

@ManyToOne
private Post post;

@ManyToOne
private User sender;

protected Comment() {};

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public User getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(User sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public Post getPost() {
    return post;
}

public void setPost(Post post) {
    this.post = post;
}


@Entity
public class Post extends ResourceSupport {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private @JsonIgnore Long id;

private String text;

@OneToMany
private List<Comment> comments;

protected Post () {};

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public List<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CommentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Comment, Long> {}


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("rest.api.repository")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

}
```

the json im using to try to post the comment into the post is

```
{
   "comment": "some text",
   "sender": "http://localhost:8090/users/1"
}
```

Comment: The json seems wrong. If the post already exists why not post it with the post id? Also, where's "sender" coming from and why is it a url to your api? And finally, are you getting any errors in either your ide or browser?

Comment: I just realised that id missed the sender out in the example (i trimmed the code down and accidentally cut it out) ill amend it now.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you have the sender that way. I would think adding the `post: ` object and the `sender: ` object to your json would be a start. But you'll need the post id. Or you could send the ids for the user and post and retrieve them from your services and add them that way; I wouldn't post them through the api. First, try to put a post through with the browser console open and let us know if you're getting any errors please.

Comment: ok. well i have tried including the post url but that didnt work either. ill experiment and let you know. also the status code i get is '204 no content'

Comment: Not the url. Say, for example, the comment is made and is not associated to the post yet. Your js code might look like `comment.post = thePost;`; same for the `sender` (if you have it).

Comment: i dont know about js really. im just calling the api in a a rest client (postman) at the moment

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that i needed to use mapped by i.e. @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post") on my comments list in my Post class.
Now i can post to http://localhost:8090/comments and then when i follow the http://localhost:8090/posts/1/comments link as before i now see the comments.